# How to define getc and putc functions for single character i/o, and provide proper buffering of i/o operations MIPS

Tags: assembly, input, output, buffer, mips

**(MIPS)** How to define **getc** and **putc** functions for single-character i/o, providing proper **buffering** of input and input operations with 512-byte buffers.
-MARS 4.5

Comment: You'll have to share what system or simulator you're using.

Comment: I'm coding assembly in MARS 4.5

Comment: Are you going to provide type `FILE` as in `int getc(FILE *stream);`?  Yes, means you might also require `fopen`/`fclose` to get a `FILE *`.

Comment: The buffering part is fairly simple -- just a matter of programming, and some data space for the buffer.  The question is how complete an implementation of C's stdio are you going for?

Comment: I want to write the result. But it require to provide proper buffering. Not having to print out each character at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you don't literally need `getc`/`putc`, just some functions that do buffered I/O and a operation for flushing the I/O under certain circumstances, like exiting the program.

(This assumes for now this buffering isn't going to be used for console I/O, i.e. file I/O only — console I/O is interactive and needs `putc` buffer flushing when using `getc`.  Further that for simplicity, you only want to be able to write to one file at a time, and read from one file at a time, though mixing put/get ok.)

Provide two global buffers, one for `putc` and one for `getc`.  Associated with each buffer is also an global variable `end`, which could be a count or a pointer as you like, and a value, `max` that is either a compile time constant or a variable, that indicates the buffer size.  Further, with each of the `putc` and `getc` is a file descriptor variable.  (Getc needs a true variable for the concept of `max`.)

---

The `putc` function takes only one argument, namely the character to put; it should enter the character into its buffer and increment the associated `end` — if the `end` reaches `max`, then write the full buffer using syscall #15 with parameters putc file descriptor (the global), putc buffer (the global) and putc max (the buffer size).  Your choice as to how to handle errors (quit program with message (probably simpler), or return error to caller?).  And then reset `end` to the beginning before returning to caller, b/c the buffer is now empty.

---

The `getc` function takes no arguments and returns a character or EOF indicator, if the buffer is not empty, then fetch character from buffer to return, and, advance the `end` position.  Before returning, if that reaches `max`, reset to the beginning.

If, however, the buffer is empty (i.e. `end` is at the beginning), then use syscall #14 to read using the getc file descriptor, the getc buffer, the getc buffer size.  If that read call gets an error, again your call as to whether to print error to console and quit program, or return error code to user (the former is probably simpler).  If it return 0, that means EOF, so return that (maybe as -1) to the caller instead of a character.

If it instead gets a non-zero number of characters, then set the `max` that number of characters, and load the char at the `end` position (which is at the beginning if you're here) to return and increment the `end` position.  Before returning if the `end` position is `max` then reset it to the beginning.

---

Initialization: the client consumer will need to put a file descriptor into `getc` and `putc`'s global file descriptors, for them to use along with their other global variables.

You will also need to provide a `flush` type of call that the `main` or other callers should use as a final operation before terminating the program.  This flush operation will use the syscall #15 to write however many characters are currently in the buffer (if more than 0, and also reset the indicators to an empty buffer).

The client should also close the files outside of getc/putc and perhaps also clear the file descriptors.  (You might consider providing an exit call that does these things.)